# Netbeans 12.0 Java hints and highlights not working

Tags: java, netbeans, highlight, macos-catalina, hints

Suddenly the hints and highlights on Netbeans stopped working for me. It won't show suggestions on imports and it won't highlights errors. I intentionally wrote `int i = "hello":`and the code wasn't highlighted and no warnings came up. I've checked >Preferences >Editor and form what I can tell Code Completion, Code Templates, Hints and Highligthing are all selected. I checked some older posts here and also tried to delete the index in the caches folder. I've discarded my project and started over, uninstalled and installed Netbeans and restarted my laptop at few times now but the issue is still there. It was working fine until yesterday afternoon. Any suggestions? I run Netbeans on macOS Catalina if that matters.

EDIT**
I now noticed this problem only occurs in projects where I have a JForm.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and here how I solved it:

1. Exit Netbeans
2. Go to : `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\NetBeans` =====> DELETE Cache folder
3. Open Netbeans and it's fixed

Comment: I tried this several times but sadly it didn't work for me, I ended up reinstalling macOS completely.